# Run laravel tinker command from .bat file windows

Tags: php, laravel, batch-file, cmd, tinker

I'm using Laravel tinker to run my script

```
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
$namafile = 'foto.jpeg';
$selectorIndex = '0';
$path = storage_path().'/app/'.$namafile;
Browsershot::url('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ds_rev_daily_l2')->select('.print', $selectorIndex)->setDelay(20000)->save($path);
```

I want to run script above with CMD Commands After Batch Script.
How can the script run from single click at `.bat` file?
Running the script from tinker from CMD Commands After Batch Script

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tinker's `execute` option to execute the given code.

Here's a sample in *bash*:

```
php artisan tinker --execute="use \App\Models\Faq; $faq = Faq::find(1); $faq->question = 'from tinker'; $faq->save();"
```

Despite this option, we can create a batch file like the one below:

```
@echo off
cd %userprofile%\project_dir
php artisan tinker --execute="use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot; $namafile = 'foto.jpeg'; $selectorIndex = '0'; $path = storage_path().'/app/'.$namafile; Browsershot::url('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ds_rev_daily_l2')->select('.print', $selectorIndex)->setDelay(20000)->save($path);"
```